# How to find which module is associated with a particular window

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a user that is being naughty and calling `SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, ... )` and finding that, naturally, their application halts at that point. While I will tell them to stop doing that I also want to know which window in the system is not responding.

By using `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` I am able to know the HWND, process ID, and thread ID of the window that is not responding. But, the process is one that loads many DLLs and any of them could be hosting that window. I need to find out which one it is.

Ideally, I would use `GetWindowLong( GWL_HINSTANCE )` to find out which module it is, but `GWL_HINSTANCE` isn't available on my Windows CE 5 platform.

Is there any other way to get the information I need?

Other ways to phrase this question:

- How can I find which HMODULE/HINSTANCE owns a particular thread ID?
- How can I find which HMODULE/HINSTANCE is associated with a particular HWND?

Answer (score 1):

Windows are not hosted or owned by modules. They are owned by threads. A window is associated with the thread that created it. Windows can be created in one module but have a window procedure that is implemented in other modules.

That said, perhaps you can find the information you need by looking at the window procedure. Find  its address with a call to GetWindowLongPtr and compare that with all the module base addresses of the process that owns the thread that created the window.

Comment: GetWindowLongPtr is not defined for Windows CE 5 / Windows Mobile 6.5.
GetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC) is defined, but the value it returns seems to be un-associated with the module base address.  CallWindowProc's docs hint that the value returned byt GWL_WNDPROC may be "a special internal value meaningful only to CallWindowProc" and therefore not an actual memory address.

Comment: @PaulH Yes, that can be the case.